# Identical Code in Block Class Overload has Different Results

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, overrides, class

The following code samples are long, but here is the issue:

If I create a custom file `/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` and add two new columns to the product grid, it works great.

If I move the file to `/app/code/local/Mycompany/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` and change `class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` to `class Mycompany_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` (plus the required XML config) the new columns are empty.

Searching those columns errors: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816`

Here is the full code:
`/app/code/local/Mycompany/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mycompany_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>Mycompany_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/Mycompany/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

```
<?php

class Mycompany_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        // Mycompany - Begin custom addition
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'fab_item_number',
            'catalog_product/item_number',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            $store->getId()
        );

        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'fab_color_code',
            'catalog_product/color_code',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            $store->getId()
        );
        // Mycompany - End custom addition

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
        ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $this->addColumn('custom_name',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
                    'index' => 'custom_name',
            ));
        }

        // Mycompany - Begin custom addition
        $this->addColumn('fab_item_number',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Item Number'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'fab_item_number',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('fab_color_code',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Color Code'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'fab_color_code',
        ));
        // Mycompany - Ens custom addition

        $this->addColumn('type',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('set_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $sets,
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sku',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'sku',
        ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn('price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
        ));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $this->addColumn('qty',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'index' => 'qty',
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('visibility',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'visibility',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'status',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('websites',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'websites',
                    'type'      => 'options',
                    'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'     => array(
                            'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                        ),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
        ));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Rss')) {
            $this->addRssList('rss/catalog/notifystock', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify Low Stock RSS'));
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this works in the /local/Mage folder but not the /local/Mycompany folder? To be clear, the block class is correctly being overloaded. The columns are being added, they just don't populate with data and can't be searched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/app/code/local/Mycompany/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

Most likely you need to define a constructor, for example:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('mycompanygrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

Also, I would try and not to simply override if you can use an event observer instead:

`core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after`

```
public function addToCatalogGridBlock($observer){
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) {
```

This way it won't break any other 3rd party modules.

Comment: The copy of the file that lives in /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php is a fully copy of the class, complete with __construct(). The copy that lives under Mycompany doesn't have any of the other methods like __construct, but I started with them all present and still had this problem. So I don't think the constructor is the issue when it comes to the Mycompany copy. I'll try the observer, and I find your point about other modules extending the same class very helpful. However, I'd also really like to understand why I have this current problem.